# Why does my date filter for today not find an item from early in the day?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am doing a filter on folder based on conditions and one is the date condition, all mails starting 07/08.

```
@SQL=("urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" > '07/08/2018 12:00AM')
```

One mail with the following time is not in the result:

> mar. 07/08/2018 01:44

Answer (score 1):

All MAPI properties are stored in the UTC time zone. If you are using DASL format, Outlook does not convert to the local TZ. You need to adjust your filter appropriately.